# Vauxhall Astra rev/rpm go high when I put my accelerator down after changing gears

Tags: clutch, gasoline, rpm, vauxhall, astra

I have a 2006 Vauxhall Astra SRI 1.8. Recently I have been experiencing an issue where after I change gear and put gas down, the car revs and seems like little/no power is actually going to the wheels. Not only is it after I change gear but just whenever I put my foot down on the accelerator significantly.

I have been assuming maybe the clutch is slipping, so a new clutch could possibly fix it? However I wanted to see if anyone here thought it could be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a clutch stall test.  From a stop, put the vehicle in a high gear and try to move the vehicle as you would normally if you were in first gear.  For example, if it is a four speed transmission start out in third or fourth.

The vehicle should stall or shudder when you lightly apply the accelerator and ease off of the clutch.  If the clutch is slipping the engine will not stall and the tachometer will increase.

A slipping clutch could be caused by, in order of likelihood, a worn out disk, weak pressure plate spring(s), a rear main oil seal leak leaking oil onto the flywheel. broken transmission/transaxle and/or engine mounts (if you have a mechanical rather than hydraulic clutch linkage).

Comment: I have a 5 speed gearbox, when I put it in fourth gear and try set off like usual the car does shudder and then stalls, does this mean it isn’t my clutch which is causing the high revs? what else could it be?

Comment: You actually have to press down a little harder on the accelerator to try and keep it from stalling to find out if the clutch is going to slip.  Do an Internet search on clutch stall test.

Comment: Got my vehicle checked and was told that it was my clutch slipping. Thanks for your help.